# Titanium: Error trying to play a sound when tapping a row in a table?

Tags: audio, titanium, tableview

I'm making a rather simple app that displays a table where each row contains an English word and the corresponding Polish word. When a row is pressed it should play a sound clip of the word expressed. However, I cannot make it work, even though I've tried to troubleshoot it with all that Google has to offer. Would appreciate if someone could point out the flaw...

```
var win = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;
var data =[];

var CustomData = [
{ file:'001', english:'Do you?', polish:'Czy masz?', fav:false },
{ file:'002', english:'How long?', polish:'Jak d?ugo?', fav:false },
{ file:'003', english:'Is it?', polish:'Czy?', fav:false },
];

var section = Ti.UI.createTableViewSection();
data.push(section);

for (var i=0; i<CustomData.length; i++) {
    var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({layout : 'vertical', height:'auto'});

    var item = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        color:'#000',
        text:CustomData[i].english,
        font:{fontSize:12, fontWeight:'bold'},
        top:3,
        left:10,
            right:30,
        height:'auto'
    });
    row.add(item);

    var cost = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        color:'#444',
        text:CustomData[i].polish,
        font:{fontSize:12},
        top:0,
        left:15,
        right:30,
        bottom:5,
        height:'auto'
    });

    row.add(cost);
    row.filter = CustomData[i].english; 
    section.add(row);
};

var tableview = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
    data:data, search:search, searchHidden:false, filterAttribute: 'filter' });

win.add(tableview);

tableview.addEventListener('click', function(e)
{
    var sound = Titanium.Media.createSound();
    sound.url = '../sound/' + e.rowData.file + '.mp3';
    sound.play();

    if (e.rowData.test)
    {
            var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
                    url:e.rowData.test,
                    title:e.rowData.title
            });
            Titanium.UI.currentTab.open(win,{animated:true});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a shot in the dark, but are you sure you can set the URL after the sound object is created?  Have you tried:

```
Titanium.Media.createSound({url:'../sound/' + e.rowData.file + '.mp3'});
```

Aside from that, are you sure the relative URL is evaluated from where you think?  Maybe try it with an absolute URL just to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question! I'm not very experienced with Titanium, so for what I know the mistake can be very beginner-ish.

I tried to format the query as you indicated: It works with an absolute URL, but not with the relative one. I guess that narrows my problem to how I pass a relative argument from the table to the eventlistener...

Comment: Ah! This worked when I also inserted a:
     row.file = CustomData[i].file;
in the for-loop...